# Gitlab: Get merge request from a commit id

Tags: php, api, gitlab

I'm using the API of gitlab and I'm building a changelog. I use merge request in my project. In my changelog I get all commits ordered by id and now I want to get the merge request of gitlab to get his message. How can I get a merge request from a commit id?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

It is an open issue in gitlab:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/28037

Comment: This was released in gitlab 10.5
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/13713